# How to switch between shared library output and executable output in libtool/autotools projects?

Tags: autotools, libtool

I have some autotools-managed project. Apart from source code files it has autogen.sh, configure.ac, Makefile.am, src/Makefile.am.

1. How to find out looking at these file if it is a library or application? For example, in Qt I have "TEMPLATE = app" or "TEMPLATE = lib" which decides this. What is it in autotools?
2. How to switch from generating a executable application to generating the library and back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Makefile.am you should have something that looks like:

> bin_PROGRAMS = foo (or sbin or something else depending on where it lands)

Change that to:

> lib_LTLIBRARIES = foo.la